# Use Model as View Element Class Name in Ember JS

Tags: javascript, css, model-view-controller, ember.js

Inside an Ember model I have a numeric priority assigned to a model; I need to pass that to an Ember view for use as a CSS class, ideally concatenated with the string 'importance-'. So for a model with importance 5, it would add the class 'importance-5' to the div generated by Ember's views. But I can't seem to find a simple way of accessing that model data from my Ember view--what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Might need a jsfiddle to fully understand what you are trying to accomplish but generally speaking the controller is the place for this. As the Ember guide says:

"controllers allow you to decorate your models with display logic."

The key is to set the content property of your controller to your active model.Then you would have a computed property on the controller:

```
importance: function() {
    return 'importance-' + this.get('priority');
}.property('priority')
```

From there you could use classBinding using {{view YourViewName classBinding=importance}}